# Color.getColor(String name) not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to change color using getColor(String name) function but it seems not to work.May be I am doing some kind of mistake. Here is the code:

```
public class ComboBoxPractice extends JFrame{

private String names={"Color.YELLOW","Color.RED","Color.GREEN"};

public ComboBoxPractice()
{
    ...

    box.addItemListener(

            new ItemListener()
            {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
                {
                    if(event.getStateChange()==event.SELECTED)
                    {
                        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getColor(names[box.getSelectedIndex()]));
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

I have also tried the String array containing Color names alone like YELLOW , RED, BLUE. but it wasn't working.

I know the other way of changing color by making an array of Class Color, but I wanted to try this method.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use the Color class as :

```
 private Color[] colors ={Color.YELLOW,Color.RED,Color.GREEN};
```

If you use the `Color` class, then you may update statement below as:

```
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getColor(names[box.getSelectedIndex()]));
```

as

```
    getContentPane().setBackground(colors[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
```

or use the names as "black", "red" etc.

```
    private String[] names={"yellow","red","green"};
```

If you decide to use the color name as above, then you may get the `Color` object using reflection as below:

```
    Field field = Color.class.getField(names[0]);
    Color color = (Color)field.get(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use reflection to get the `Color` instances from the field names, e.g.:

```
Field field = Color.class.getField("YELLOW");
Color c = (Color)field.get(null);
```

Notice how the color string doesn't contain the actual class name. For this application it would look like this:

```
Field field = Color.class.getField(names[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
Color backgroundColor = (Color)field.get(null);
```